# Apply paging and sorting on redis object directly

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using Redis cache to store my Page data. I need to show that data paginated (lazy loading) on my page. When the records are lower in number, everything works fine. But when its loaded with more than 60k records, it slows enormously. I am using following code to fetch data:

```
List<MyEntity> lstMyData = cont.Cache.GetObject<List<MyEntity>>("RedisKeyName")
                               .Where(x => x.Id == Id || x.Id == 0)
                               .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalCount)
                               .Skip((page != 0 ? page - 1 : 0) * limit)
                               .Take(limit)
                               .ToList();
```

I need to query on Redis object directly rather than fetch full list every time, but couldn't find anything appropriate. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you storing these records in Redis `LIST`?

Comment: No, storing in Redis Object.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does too much work, e.g. iterating the list to get all records with the given id (`O(N)`), sorting the resulting list (`O(Nlog(N))`), and do the pagination work (`O(N/2)` in average). When there are too many records, it should be very slow. You need to redesign the way of storing data.

> Use Redis' `SORTED SET` to improve the performance.

Storing all records of a given `Id` in a `SORTED SET`, with the `TotalCount` of the record as score.

When you need to fetch the data, you can use the `ZREVRANGE` command to do the pagination work in `O(log(N) + limit)`, `N` is the number of records for the given `Id`. It should be much faster.

```
// add records for Id1
zadd Id1 TotalCount1 record1
zadd Id1 TotalCount2 record2
// ...
zadd Id1 TotalCountN recordN
// pagination for the given Id, page (beginning from 1) and limit
zrevrange Id1 (page-1)*limit page*limit-1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have searched about sorted sets, they are good for paging, but can i sort on multiple fields using sorted sets as it is sorted by score?

Comment: @AhmedHassan Since it sorts by score (in fact, you can also sort by member in lexicographical order, if all elements have the same score, i.e. `zrangebylex`), if you want to sort on multiple fields, you have to do some trick, i.e. generate a score with multiple fields. For example, assume you want to sort on both `A` and `B`, and `B` is in range of `[0 - 9]`, then you can generate a score like this: `A * 10 + B`. If you CANNOT generate such a score, you CANNOT sort on multiple fields.